# Find and replace and modify string using regular expressions in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'm pretty sure I need to use Regular Expressions in Notepad++ (or similar) to bulk update a list of web pages that contain URL's that need modifying slightly.  The problem I'm having is that I have a few hundred pages that contain this kind of format for a URL:

http://www.test.co.uk/folder1/folder2/pagename.html

.. this structure now needs to be changed to:

http://www.test.co.uk/folder1/folder2/pagename/index.html

.. so the main part of the URL remains unchanged, but the 'pagename' needs to lose the .html part only and instead should now be proceeded by '/index.html' - in other words the 'pagename' becomes another sub-folder for the full URL.

I'm sure there must be a way of retaining most of the URL string using "Find in files.." in Notepad++ using Reg Exp and also do the work required to remove the .html part of the 'pagename' and then append '/index.html' - I would be really grateful for any help.  Thanks in advance!  Dennis.

Comment: You don't really need regex to do that. Can't you use a simple find/replace?

Comment: is there always to folder levels or does it vary?

Comment: Depending on the content of your files, a regex is not needed, you could just replace `.html`  for `/index.html`. The only problem with this approach would be if your files had `.html`s that you don't want to match (in that case, a regex should be necessary).

Comment: Thanks acdcjunior - you mention the problem I have with other URL's in the HTML - I forgot to put this in my original question! I've expanded further in my comment to the first answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want this to affect all urls, you can do this without regex:**

Find

```
.html
```

Replace with:

```
/index.html
```

---

**If you want this to only affect urls containing `folder1/folder2`, you can do this with regex:**

Find

```
folder1/folder2/(.*)\.html
```

Replace with:

```
folder1/folder2/\1/index.html
```

Comment: If that would work, then you could even do find `.html` replace with `/`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've just realised I didn't include some important info in my original question. 

There are other URL's in the page HTML that need to remain unchanged (so ignored by find/replace), but in the code there are URL's as in my example, with the common factor being the 'folder1/folder2' part.  So only URL's with this in should be found and then the URL updated for the new structure. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Many thanks arserbin3 - that's what I needed!  I changed \1 to $1 as my version of Notepad++ seems to require that notation.  Many thanks again!!